# Intercepting RecyclerView downwards fling in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have the following layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="com.example.CardViewBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fixedBanner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <!-- random content -->
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/card2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

When scrolling down (finger goes upwards) from `fixedBanner` or `card1`, the `appBarLayout` collapses first, then `nestedScrollView` scrolls down. However, if scrolling down from `recyclerView`, `recyclerView` starts scrolling.  I want `nestedScrollView` to scroll down first before `recyclerView`.

I have tried using a custom `CardViewBehavior` set on `nestedScrollView` which overrides onNestedPreScroll to consume scroll deltas if `appBarLayout` is not fully collapsed and there is still range to scroll in `nestedScrollView`.

However, if I swipe fast enough on `recyclerView`, `recyclerView` starts flinging before `nestedScrollView` has fully scrolled to bottom.  I tried overriding `onNestedPreFling` and `onNestedFling` in `CardViewBehavior`, but it seems those two methods were never called when RecyclerView starts flinging by itself.

How can I ensure that `nestedScrollView` scrolls to bottom before `recyclerView` starts scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Henry, I have successfully recreate the behaviour from [the article](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2018/01/experimenting-with-nested-scrolling.html) you mentioned by @AlexLockwood in kotlin. I've dealing with this problem for two days, the other answers usually suggest using `WRAP_CONTENT` attribute and basically defeat the purpose of `RecyclerView` as the `View` is not being recycled anymore. I'm providing the code below just in case this may help someone in the future.

```kotlin
class NestedScrollLayout(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?
) : NestedScrollView(context, attrs),
    NestedScrollingParent3 {

    private var parentHelper = NestedScrollingParentHelper(this)

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int): Boolean {
        return (axes and ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0
    }

    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int) {
        parentHelper.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes)
        startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int) {
        if(target is RecyclerView) {
            if ((dy < 0 && isRvScrolledToTop(target)) || (dy > 0 && !isNsvScrolledToBottom(this))) {
                scrollBy(0, dy)
                consumed[1] = dy
                return
            }
        }
        dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, null, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int,
        type: Int
    ) {
        val oldScrollY = scrollY
        scrollBy(0, dyUnconsumed)
        val mConsumed = scrollY - oldScrollY
        val mUnconsumed = dyUnconsumed - mConsumed
        dispatchNestedScroll(0, mConsumed, 0, mUnconsumed, null, type)
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View, type: Int) {
        parentHelper.onStopNestedScroll(target, type)
        stopNestedScroll(type)
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(child: View, target: View, axes: Int): Boolean {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "NestedScrollLayout:onStartNestedScroll", "Requested")
        return onStartNestedScroll(child, target, axes, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH)
    }

    override fun onNestedScrollAccepted(child: View, target: View, axes: Int) {
        onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray) {
        onNestedPreScroll(target, dx, dy, consumed, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(
        target: View,
        dxConsumed: Int,
        dyConsumed: Int,
        dxUnconsumed: Int,
        dyUnconsumed: Int
    ) {
        onNestedScroll(
            target,
            dxConsumed,
            dyConsumed,
            dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed,
            ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH
        )
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(target: View) {
        onStopNestedScroll(target, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH)
    }

    override fun getNestedScrollAxes(): Int {
        return parentHelper.nestedScrollAxes
    }

    companion object {
        private fun isNsvScrolledToBottom(nsv: NestedScrollView): Boolean {
            return !nsv.canScrollVertically(1)
        }

        private fun isRvScrolledToTop(rv: RecyclerView): Boolean {
            rv.layoutManager?.let { lm ->
                return when (lm) {
                    is LinearLayoutManager -> {
                        lm.findViewByPosition(0)?.top == 0 && lm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0
                    }
                    is GridLayoutManager -> {
                        lm.findViewByPosition(0)?.top == 0 && lm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0
                    }
                    is StaggeredGridLayoutManager -> {
                        lm.findViewByPosition(0)?.top == 0 && lm.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(
                            intArrayOf(0)
                        )[0] == 0
                    }
                    else -> lm.findViewByPosition(0)?.top == 0
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can use `NestedScrollLayout` as follows:

```xml
<com.organization.appname.NestedScrollLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />

    ...

</com.organization.appname.NestedScrollLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend `NestedScrollView` and override the `onNestedPreScroll` method directly.

(Solution was found on https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2018/01/experimenting-with-nested-scrolling.html)